# Does strip_tags leave <br> untouched? If no, how can I add a <br> on every three sentences?

Tags: php

Hello I am building a simple aggregator script and I am trying to have a better result. 
Using strip_tags I remove all the html code.

It would be great if I could live all the `<br>` on it but I dont know if there is a way.

So, my question is how can i add a `<br>` at the end of every third sentence in the post. I guess you have to use pregex or strpos. 

I know how to find a dot but how can I count them?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add the accepted tags to strip_tags as second parameter

ex.

```
strip_tags($text, '<br>');
```